# "stat" says "permission denied", even though all the permissions are in place

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, directory

I have this:

```
ls -al /home/my_user/dir1/dir2/file1.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 http http 2798 Dec 30 18:18 /home/my_user/dir1/dir2/file1.txt
```

However, I can't stat it:

```
sudo -u http stat /home/my_user/dir1/dir2/file1.txt
stat: cannot stat '/home/my_user/dir1/dir2/file1.txt': Permission denied
```

Why? How to fix that without having to `chmod 777 <path>`, is there more approprivate way

?

Comment: Check the permissions of all the containing directories.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to verify the permissions of each folder involved in the path before you get to the file itself.

Many Linux distributions default the permissions to (0700) (meaning just the user itself is allow to read/write/execute), to each folder inside the `/home` directory, which means that if user `my_user` has a file `/home/my_user/dir1/dir2/file1.txt` with the permissions `0755` the user `http` can't stat it because the default permissions I mentioned above will prevent it.

My guess is that when you executed the `ls -al /home/my_user/dir1/dir2/file1.txt` was with a user other than `http` and that user could actually read the file. If that is the case, you have to correct the permissions on all the directories with tools like `chmod` or `setfacl` if you want to be more specific.

I hope this helps.